# Saving and printing a matrix from another file in a function

Tags: c, function, pointers, matrix

This program should call a function that opens an external file and browse it counting the rows of it, then it creates a pointer to a matrix and browses again the file but now saving its data on the matrix and returns that matrix, after that it will print the matrix.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int tam;
float **carga_archivo(char *nombre_archivo);
int main()
{
    int i,j;
    char *nombre_archivo="Agua_Vapor.txt";
    float **agua_vapor=carga_archivo(nombre_archivo);
    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; i < tam; i++)
            printf("%f   ", agua_vapor[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
float **carga_archivo(char *nombre_archivo)
{
    int i=0;
    float P[300][6];
    FILE *archivo;
    archivo=fopen(nombre_archivo,"r");
    while(!feof(archivo))
    {
        i++;
        fscanf(archivo,"%f\t%f\t%f\t%f\t%f\t%f\n",
                  &P[0][i],&P[1][i],&P[2][i],&P[3][i],&P[4][i],&P[5][i]);
            //This part is just so the program can read the file line per line,
            //else it would count character per character, doesn't really do anything
            //(I didn't know the command or condition to do it other way
    }
    tam=i;
    printf("%i",tam);
    int filas = 6;
    int columnas = tam;
    float **M = (float **)malloc(filas*sizeof(float*));
    for (i=0;i<filas;i++)
        M[i] = (float*)malloc(columnas*sizeof(float));
    for (i = 0; i < columnas; ++i)
        fscanf(archivo,"%f\t%f\t%f\t%f\t%f\t%f\n",&M[0][i],&M[1][i],
                                       &M[2][i],&M[3][i],&M[4][i],&M[5][i]);
    fclose (archivo);
    return M;
}
```

The problem here is that when the matrix should be printed the program crashes, I know the program does saves the data, since when I print it directly inside the function I does prints, so I think it might be ether the way I'm declaring the matrix or the function or the way I'm calling to the function.

**Edit**: The content of the file it calls is just a data set separated by tabulations.

> 0.06  36.16   23.739  2425.0  2567.4  8.3304
>
> 0.06  80.00   27.132  2487.3  2650.1  8.5804
>
> 0.06  120.00  30.219  2544.7  2726.0  8.7840
>
> 0.06  160.00  33.302  2602.7  2802.5  8.9693
>
> 0.06  200.00  36.383  2661.4  2879.7  9.1398
>
> 0.06  240.00  39.462  2721.0  2957.8  9.2982
>
> 0.06  280.00  42.540  2781.5  3036.8  9.4464
>
> 0.06  320.00  45.618  2843.0  3116.7  9.5859
>
> 0.06  360.00  48.696  2905.5  3197.7  9.7180
>
> 0.06  400.00  51.774  2969.0  3279.6  9.8435

(you can't note the tabulations but they are there)

Any correction is welcome.

Comment: Your indices for `P` seem to be the wrong way around. Or its declaration.

Comment: Your code has many problem. Show sample of contents of `Agua_Vapor.txt`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/3185968

Comment: You also never rewind `archivo`, so all the `fscanf()`s in the `for`-loop will fail.

Comment: Sorry, already corrected, but I still don't get that about "rewind `archivo`"

Comment: The data constructs you `printf` and `scanf` are **no** matrices, aka 2D array, nor can they point to one. A pointer is not an array!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fix like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define COLS 6
int tam;

float **carga_archivo(const char *nombre_archivo);

int main(void){
    int i,j;
    const char *nombre_archivo= "Agua_Vapor.txt";
    float **agua_vapor = carga_archivo(nombre_archivo);

    for (i = 0; i < tam; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
            printf("%f   ", agua_vapor[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    //deallocate agua_vapor
    return 0;
}

float **carga_archivo(const char *nombre_archivo){
    float P[300][COLS];
    FILE *archivo = fopen(nombre_archivo, "r");
    int i= 0;

    while(i < 300 && COLS==fscanf(archivo, "%f\t%f\t%f\t%f\t%f\t%f\n", &P[i][0],&P[i][1],&P[i][2],&P[i][3],&P[i][4],&P[i][5])){
        i++;
    }
    fclose(archivo);
    tam=i;
    //printf("%i",tam);
    int rows = tam, columnas = COLS;
    float **M = malloc(rows * sizeof(float*));
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++){
        M[i] = malloc(columnas*sizeof(float));
        for(int j = 0; j < columnas; ++ j)
            M[i][j] = P[i][j];
    }
    return M;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, thats exactly what I needed, but could you explain a little what you did there or where I was wrong?

Comment: Specifically, what part do you want to ask? Because there are so many.